# Laravel ajax search with relations

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I wanted to search the records after getting the relations. I tried with Laravel colletions. didnt work tough.

```
public function search($key){
    $products = Product::with('unit', 'category', 'brand')->get();
    $allproducts = collect($products);
    $result = $allproducts->search($key);
```

Here I want the search to be done also based on category and brand.
If I cant you collection then how to do it the standard way.

Comment: you want to search for an Id or for a keyword?

Comment: I want search with keyword

Comment: and you want to search inside eloquent collection or a query is fine too?

Comment: query on eloquent collection will be easy. but I think i will lose some performance. Its an ajax search so query is fine.

Comment: what are you looking for? a product title, description, what?

Comment: Its a common searchbar.  I needed to search and show as a  table of products where the keyword matches on product_name or price or category_name or brand_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a query is the best approach since you dont need to load all products-categories-etc from the database and then try to find the matching ones.

Example query

```
Product::where('product_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->orWhereHas('category', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
            $q->where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        //everything else you need to check
        })->get();
```